# Create symmetric matrix from flattened lower triangular vector

Tags: julia

If I have the lower triangular flattened vector of elements, how do I convert this to the symmetric matrix easily in Julia?

In Numpy, I create an nxn matrix, and use np.tril_indices to index into it and fill it in with my flat vector.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a direct solution but you can do (easy, but not very efficient):

```
julia> m = zeros(5, 5)
5×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

julia> m[axes(m, 1) .>= axes(m, 2)'] = 1001:1015
1001:1015

julia> m
5×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 1001.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
 1002.0  1006.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
 1003.0  1007.0  1010.0     0.0     0.0
 1004.0  1008.0  1011.0  1013.0     0.0
 1005.0  1009.0  1012.0  1014.0  1015.0
```

or define a custom function:

```
function tril_indices(M)
    n = size(M, 1)
    return collect(Iterators.flatten(((n+1)*i-n:n*i) for i in 1:n))
end
```

Comment: The question asks for a symmetric matrix, not a triangular one. It's not entirely clear what the OP wants, but I suspect adding a Symmetric( m, :L ) will give them what they need.

Comment: It was not fully clear for me what OP wanted either as `np.tril_indices` does not produce a symmetric matrix, so I have shown how to reproduce this function since it was explicitly mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you have a square matrix, and you index it with np.tril_indices, that gives you a flat vector that you can then assign to some other flattened vector

Comment: Yes, the same is in Julia in my implementation.